# Staying Logged In Using Requests and Python

Tags: python-requests

I am trying to log onto a website using python and requests. I'm pretty sure I am logging on properly. The next part is I go to a different page and try to download a file from that page. However, in order to download the file you have to be logged in. When I go to download the file, however, it redirects me to the log-in menu saying I haven't logged in. I am stuck and don't know what to do! By the way, the website is grabcad.com, what I'm basically trying to do is press the download all button featured on such a page
http://grabcad.com/library/apple-ipod-touch-5th-gen-1

```
payload = {'member[email]': 'username', 'member[password]': 'pass'}
with requests.Session() as s:
    rObject = s.post('http://www.grabcad.com/login', data=payload)
    cookies = rObject.cookies

    rObject = s.get('http://www.grabcad.com' + downloadUrl, cookies=cookies)
    #download URL is something I obtain early and I know it's correct. It's the URL for when you press the downloadAll button

    path = 'C:\\User\\Desktop\\filename
    with open(path, 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in rObject.iter_content():
            f.write(chunk)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I took an altogether different route to solve the problem, I simply used mechanize which is an automated browswer tool for python.

```
#how to use mechanize to log-in, specifically for grabcad
b.open('http://grabcad.com/login')
b.form = list(b.forms())[1]
control = b.form.find_control("member[email]")
control2 = b.form.find_control("member[password]")
control.value = 'username'
control2.value = 'pass'
b.submit()

#Download Part
path = 'C:\\User\\Desktop\\filename
b.retrieve('https://www.grabcad.com' + downloadUrl, path)
#downloadUrl is obtained earlier and is simply the URL for the download
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you ensuring that you're logged in correctly?  I would print out the html after sending that post request from the session object & ensure it isn't a login page or an invalid password page.  Cookies are automatically persistent across requests made on the session object, so I believe that the initial login isn't successful (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects).

Personally, I would use [selenium](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium) for this though.

I have correctly logged into grabcad with the following code:

```
import requests
s = requests.session()
payload = {'member[email]': 'yourEmail', 'member[password]': 'yourPassword'}
p = s.post('https://grabcad.com/login', data=payload) # Ensure you're posting to HTTPS
```

Comment: How would you use Selenium for this? How do you account for the dialog box that pops up? I am automating this task for a large number of files, and I can't sit around and click every single dialog box.

Could you also be more specific in terms of ways I can check that I logged on correctly?

Comment: With selenium, I would open a new webbrowser instance, direct it to login.  Then go to the download page and click the element.  To handle multiple windows in selenium, take a look at this: [window_handles](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.window_handles)  - You will not need to manually click anything.  With requests module, to ensure that you're correctly logged in, try doing 'print rObject.text' and looking through the HTML to see if it is still asking you to login.

Comment: 1) You were right. I am not logging in correctly. However, I have no idea why I am not logging in correctly. Should I post that as a separate question?

2) As I suspected, Selenium doesn't detect the download dialog box as being another window.

Comment: @user2529952 Updated answer above.  I believe all you need to change is HTTP to HTTPS in the login url.